# UINavigationController Push Segue doesn't work in iOS11, No back button, No title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, ios11

I have a `tabbar` with a `navigation controller` , when I present a new storyboard to the view a `navigation controller` as it's initial controller.

[image]

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name:"AccountMenu", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"AccountMenuRootVC") as! AccountMenuRootVC
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Result works as expected in ios 10

[image]

But in ios 11, navigation controller doesn't work.

Looks like initial navigation controller stuck up there and doesn't update.

[image]

I have also tried adding this, but no luck

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it works fine in iOS11 also.

Comment: @JD. Where is the back button and title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, answer was in somewhere else, My initial segue after login was a custom segue

https://github.com/oyvind-hauge/OHCircleSegue/blob/master/OHCircleSegue/OHCircleSegue.swift

turns out `CAAnimationDelegate` functions were never called 
but 
`window?.insertSubview(destView!, aboveSubview: sourceView!)`
was replacing the view so adding the following to custom segue solved the issue.

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    source.present(destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```